# Right shift operator for signed numbers

Tags: c++, c

I am reading about shift operators in C.

Right shifting n bits divides by 2 raise to n. Shifting signed values may fail because for negative values the result never gets past -1: `-5 >> 3` is `-1` and not `0` like `-5/8`.

My question is why shifting signed values may fail?

Why value of `-5 >> 3` is `-1` and not zero?

Kindly explain.

Comment: Because right shift duplicates the sign bit. If you start with negative number, you will end with negative number (all ones in binary, which is -1 in 2's complement).

Comment: @oakad for example -5 is represented as 1000 0101 for one byte. If we do right shift for we ge 1111 0000. How we get -1?

Comment: @venkysmarty -5 in 8 bits is 11111011. Shift right by 3 will give you 11111111. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: A bit of unsolicited advice: Only use bit shifting when you actually care about patterns of bits. When you care about the value of the variable as an actual integer, then use arithmetic operations. Also, when you do use bit shifting, only do it on unsigned types. It's implementation dependent what happens if you bit shift a negative integer.

Comment: @Corbin: a *negative* signed integer. Bit shifting of positive signed integers is well defined as far as you stay in their range. (just nitpicking, +1 for the rest)

Comment: @oakad: the behaviour of right shift on signed quantities is not guaranteed to be a arithmetic shift (shifting in the same bit as the most significant bit) or a logical shift (shifting in zeros); both are permissible according to the standard.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Whoops, thought it was undefined in general for signed types. Thanks!

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Op was asking why he's getting the value he's getting. The standard, on the other hand, has to consider odd Univacs still hanging around, which may behave differently. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is simply implementation-defined:

From 5.8 Shift operators

> The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and
>   integral promotions are performed. The type of the result is that of
>   the promoted left operand. The behavior is undefined if the right
>   operand is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of
>   the promoted left operand
>
> [...]
>
> If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined.

Comment: You seem to have mixed up left and right. The relevant quote is "If E1
has a signed type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined" (not undefined).

Answer (score -1):

Shifting with signed integers is  implementation defined, but if the architecture you're using has an arithmetic shift, you can pretty reliably guess it with use it.

It's because of how negative numbers are stored in the computer. It's called two's complement. To switch the sign of a two's complement, you `NOT` its bits and add 1. For example, with an 8 bit integer `00011010` (26), first you `NOT` to get `11100101`, then you add 1 and get `11100110` (-26). The problem comes from that most  significant bit being set. If when you shifted it put 0s in at the left, the number would become positive, but if it put 1s, then the lowest possible result is `11111111` which is -1. This is how arithmetic shifts work, when you shift the computer adds bits that are the same as the left most bit.

So to be explicit, this is what is happening (using 8 bit integers because it's easier and the size is arbitrary in this case): `11111011` gets shifted 3 to the right (so `011` goes away) and since the most significant bit is set 3 `1`s are inserted at the top, so you get `11111111` which is -1.

Comment: This case is implementation-defined, not undefined.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for the correction.